# Require encrypted assertion for Spring SAML Service Provider

Tags: spring-saml

I am using Spring SAML and have a service provider configured that accepts encrypted assertions. Is there a way to configure the SP so that it rejects assertions that are not encrypted?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't configure Spring SAML to enforce this rule. The easiest way to get it in place is to extend `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl`, override e.g. method `processAuthenticationResponse` and throw `org.opensaml.xml.security.SecurityException` in case the assertion isn't encrypted.